# How can I deal with other people broadening my question when I have tried and failed to keep it focused?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Is a prospective boss with a history of quick hirings and firings a "proceed with caution" or "do not proceed"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19490/is-a-prospective-boss-who-is-hiring-after-firings-a-proceed-with-caution-or-d) , which was recently closed as too opinion based, was intended as a narrow question. One prospective employer hired two or three people and then fired them very quickly, taking a nasty view of them. What I wanted to know was, as I explicitly stated, from a human resources perspective, is working with him a "proceed with caution" or a nonstarter?

The comments broaden the question appreciably. One person broadened it to include whether I was competent for job title X, and my attempt to say, "I asked question A, not question B. I would like your answer to A, and if I want input on question B, I will raise that in a separate question." But it failed; the question was now both whether the boss was a nonstarter from an HR perspective and whether my competencies matched the position. And other things retrofitted my question to be in an elastic sense more about "Should I take job Y," which was off limits.

What, if anything, could I have done to retain focus on what is now closed as a too opinion-based question? I asked a question about a very narrow topic, but it seems to have been subject to a minor brainstorm, and that brainstorm seemed to pave the way to go from my explicit, narrow intent to be more open-ended.

What would be helpful in this case? Should I have just said "I am interested in knowing whether, from a human resources perspective, being hired after a boss has quickly hired and fired two or three other programmers and has nasty things to say about them, is a nonstarter or proceed with caution; if I have other questions, I will bring them up in separate notes?" The closing of the question as opinion-based seems like I wasn't the only person who didn't like the open-ended "Should I take job X?" question the discussion turned to.

Answer (score 4):

This site is not your typical workplace forum.  We are a Q&A Site that is focused on questions that are answerable objectively and completely.  The question you want to ask is basically a poll of our users about what they think about your situation.  That sort of thing is something we actively attempt to avoid here.  The question you have asked can not really be answered in an objective and complete way.

The comments have been an attempt to help you get the question reopened.  If you do not want to change the question to meet the standards of the site then the question will likely remain closed.  You marked an answer as accepted so it seems that you have an answer that works for you.  So leaving the question closed should not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

One of our fantastic, insightful editors took a moment to slightly reword some things in the question to make it a better fit. The answers explain *how you can decide* how to proceed. The answers are objective and include plenty of reasoning. In short, they're the types of answers we're looking for from [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

While it's true the answers are "it depends", the objectivity presented in both the questions and answers influenced my call to reopen the post. In questions like this, we can't necessarily make decisions for you, but we can definitely tell you *how* to make a decision.